# Caminhamento por nível em árvore binária

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária

Descrição do problema que preciso resolver:
"Um caminhamento por nível em uma árvore, primeiro lista a raiz, em seguida todos os nós que estão no nível 1 então todos os nós do nível 2, etc. Escreva um procedimento para listar os nós de uma árvore binária por nível."

Como é necessário percorrer uma árvore binária, utilizei recursividade na escrita do método, mas não consigo obter o resultado esperado. Segue o método que eu escrevi:

```
public void imprimeNivel(No no) {
    if(no != null) {

        if(no == raiz) {
            System.out.println(raiz.getConteudo());
        } 
            if(no.getFilhoDireita() == null && no.getFilhoEsquerda() == null) {

            } else if(no.getFilhoDireita() == null) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", no.getFilhoEsquerda().getConteudo());
            } else if(no.getFilhoEsquerda() == null) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", no.getFilhoDireita().getConteudo());
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%d ", no.getFilhoEsquerda().getConteudo());
                System.out.printf("%d ", no.getFilhoDireita().getConteudo());
            }

            System.out.println();
            imprimeNivel(no.getFilhoEsquerda());
            imprimeNivel(no.getFilhoDireita());

    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma ideia de como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 5):

## Código

O código do algoritmo mais direto e simples que eu conheço para percorrer a árvore em níveis é usando uma fila:

```
public void walkLevels(No no) {
    if (no == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tree node cannot be null!");
    Deque<No> fila = new ArrayDeque<>();
    fila.add(no);
    while (!fila.isEmpty()) {
        No atual = fila.removeFirst();
        System.out.printf("%s, ", atual.getConteudo());
        if (atual.getFilhoEsquerda() != null) fila.add(atual.getFilhoEsquerda());
        if (atual.getFilhoDireita() != null) fila.add(atual.getFilhoDireita());
    }
}
```

## Algoritmo

A ideia básica do algoritmo é:

1. Inicie com a raiz
2. Consuma o primeiro nó da fila
3. Adicione os filhos dele, se tiver algum, no final da fila fila
4. Repita os passos 2 e 3 até limpar a fila

Como os nós filhos são adicionados sempre ao final da fila, isto garante que todos os nós do nível anterior serão executados antes do próximo nível.

## Teste de mesa

Usando como exemplo a [árvore](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/Binary_search_tree.svg) da [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria_de_busca):

[image: Árvore binária de exemplo]

Podemos fazer uma representação da execução assim:

```
    Fila      Ação
0   -         Início, coloca o nó raiz na fila   
1   8         Consome 8,  adiciona filhos 3 e 10 ao final   
2   3 10      Consome 3,  adiciona filhos 1 e 6 ao final       
3   10 1 6    Consome 10, adiciona filho 14 da direita ao final        
4   1 6 14    Consome 1,  sem filhos então nada a fazer        
5   6 14      Consome 6,  adiciona filhos 4 e 7 ao final      
6   14 4 7    Consome 14, adiciona filho 13 da esquerda ao final        
7   4 7 13    Consome 4,  sem filhos então nada a fazer                    
8   7 13      Consome 7,  sem filhos então nada a fazer      
9   13        Consome 13, sem filhos então nada a fazer    
10  -         Fila vazia --> Terminou!
```

#### [Código completo no meu GitHub](https://github.com/utluiz/java-playground/blob/master/random-code/src/main/java/WalkTreeLevels.java)